# Unable to force landscape only in activity (manifest correctly set up)

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-orientation

I'm having trouble to set my activity to be displayed in landscape. Before you all tag this as a duplicate, I've obviously used `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in my AndroidManifest.xml for the specific activity, with no success. I've also tried setting it on the `onCreate` method like this: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` without any success either.

I'm using a custom theme who kinda regroup everything I've found on the internet, that's supposed to be " the correct way to force the landscape mode " but none of those is working either, here's my theme :

```
 <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

MyMaterialTheme.Base ( parent ) :

```
 <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/header_background_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and here's my full AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.*****.launcher" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".PlayerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:configChanges="density|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|uiMode">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="***"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  </application>
```

I must admit that I'm totally flabbergasted, I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have an idea of what's happening?

Comment: The flags configChanges"orientation" will prevent it to resize to landscape before it is show. Tryed simply removing all configChanges listeners?

Comment: i'll try this right now, i'll update you.
Where do you get this info that the flag prevents any resizing ?
Update : my app now crash lol

Comment: Dont remember, but also experience, the configChanges="orientation" prevents the screen from being recreated on rotation, but it will also not go trough layout phases and onCreate

Comment: Updated the comment above

Comment: crash is good, post te stacktrace

Comment: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 21814 (escale.launcher)
                                                              
                                                              [ 02-16 15:04:39.281   468:  468 W/         ]
                                                              debuggerd: handling request: pid=21814 uid=10284 gid=10284 tid=21814

Comment: weird stacktrace, happens only when on portrait mode

Comment: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.db>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail; ( my apologies, the last one was the Error Logcat

Comment: In your code where you request to be on LANDSCAPE add a return, since it will get trough lifecycle again, the webpage can start loading before rotating

Comment: it's on the `onCreate` method

Comment: Yes, add a return after checking if it is on PORTRAIT

Comment: i cant really code anything in the manifest ... and on the oncreate method, i only call the `setRequestedOrientation` method ...

Comment: Do a if(currentOrientation == PORTRAIT) then dont load the webview, it will get created at ladnscape

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos im afraid im not following you ... we're not talking about the same thing i guess, i havent referenced a webview anywhere in my code, nor in my question

Comment: Hmm... I was sure you did, cause of the stack trace, you will need to add info about the Activity your have

Comment: But anyway.. you dont need to do setContentView if currentOrientaiton = PORTRAIT